# Picklist options shows [object Object]

Tags: tabulator

When feeding options into a tabulator table, options dislpay as [object Object].

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why pictures of text vs. actual text? That's much less helpful.

Comment: You defined your `values` as an array of objects.  So you're seeing each value represented as an object. You need to reread the documentation for how to set that up.

Comment: As for documentation, I read and re-read it about a 1000 times. I am structuring exactly as the documentation is telling me but will check again.

Comment: http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/edit#edit-builtin outlines how values can be passed to the picklist:

{title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"select", editorParams:{
    values:[
        {
            label:"Steve Boberson",
            value:"steve",
        },
        {
            label:"Bob Jimmerson",
            value:"bob",
        },
        {
            label:"Jenny Jillerson",
            value:"jenny",
        },
        {
            label:"Jill Betterson",
            value:"jill",
        },
    ]
}}

Answer (score 0):

The relevant documentation is screenshotted below and linked [here](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.8/edit#edit-builtin) under the "Select" heading.

Just do this:

```
{ <other_config>
    editorParams:{
      showListOnEmpty: true,
      allowEmpty: true,
      values:{
          "123":"Wild Bunch",
          "345":"Gulf",
          "678":"Duch Film Works",
      }
}}
```

`<other_config>` is just a placeholder for text from your image that I was not going to retype for you; do not enter `<other_config>` *literally*.

[image]

Comment: Yep, I tried that but selecting "Steve Boberson" gives me a display value in the cell "steve" but I cannot have that. I need to display "Wild Bunch" but store an Id of "123". Using this way, if I select "Wild Bunch", the user will see 123 in the cell. :(

Comment: If you make a minimal reproducible example, I might hack at it. But as is, I've done all I can. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example